# Как оптимизировать данный код по памяти?

Tags: java, оптимизация

Проблема: код работает, но превышает лимита памяти (Ограничение памяти 64МБ).

Выходные данные (ожидаются в стандартном потоке вывода) - одно целое число.

**Пример 1:**

*Ввод:*
`4` `6`
`199`
`453`
`220`
`601`

*Вывод:*
`200`

**Пример 2**

*Ввод:*
`2` `100`
`99`
`1`

*Вывод:*
`1`

**Пример 3**

*Ввод:*
`2` `100`
`98`
`1`

*Вывод:*
`0`

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long pays = 0L; // максимальное количество выплаты на одного менеджера
        try {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            String str = scan.nextLine();  //считываем строку
            int n = Integer.parseInt(str.split(" ")[0]); //распарсили первых два числа
            int m = Integer.parseInt(str.split(" ")[1]);
            long[] acc = new long[n]; // создаем массив для хранения значения каждого корпоративного счета
            long summa = 0L; // общая сумма со всех счетов
            for (int i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) { // считываем все счета и помещаем их в массив плюс находим общую сумму на всех счетах
                acc[i] = Long.parseLong(scan.nextLine());
                summa += acc[i];
            }

            if(summa > 0 && m > 0)
                pays = summa/m; //здесь получаем максимально возможную выплату на каждого менеджера
            if(pays != 0) {
                while(true) { // а здесь как раз самая долгая часть выполнения программы
                    int g = 0; // переменная для хранения количества менеджеров для которых хватит выплатить денег с одного счета
                    for (int i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {   // перебираем все счета
                        g += acc[i] / pays; // узнаем скольким менеджерам хватит выплатить указанное в pays количество денег
                    }
                    if(g >= m)
                        break; // если всем менеджерам хватает данной выплаты то завершаем программу
                    else
                        pays--; // если не всем менеджерам хватает выплаты то сумму выплат уменьшаем на единицу
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {}
        finally {
            System.out.println(pays); // выводим результат
        }
    }
}
```

P.s Описание задачи:

> У Петра Васильевича открыто N корпоративных счетов, на которых лежат разные суммы денег Cn, а в компании работает M менеджеров.
> Необходимо выяснить максимальный размер премии, которую можно отправить с учетом условий. Если денег на счетах компании не
> хватит на то, чтобы выдать премию хотя бы по 1 у.е. - значит премии не будет, и нужно вывести 0.
> Входные данные (поступают в стандартный поток ввода)
> Первая строка - целые числа N и M через пробел (1≤N≤100 000, 1≤M≤100 000)
> Далее N строк, на каждой из которых одно целое число Cn (0≤Cn≤100 000 000)

Comment: Опишите, что должен делать код

Comment: Задача много раз была здесь. А на что в данном коде память уходит - совсем непонятно.

Answer (score 0):

Память уходит сюда:

```
long[] acc = new long[n];
```

А надо по идее:

```
int[] acc = new int[n];
```

`long summa;` сохранить - это разумно.

**Update**

Можно попробовать дальше оптимизировать по памяти, предполагая, что у Петра Васильевича много счетов с нулевым балансом. Тогда надо применить коллекцию `SparseArray` (разряженный массив) - он отсутствует в стандартной реализации JDK, но есть в разных сторонних либах - гугл в помощь.